# Blotchy noise in cycles render with denoise

Tags: rendering

When I was rendering my image, I noticed that it looks weird (top left, and right side). I don't know what causes this issue, never had it before.

[image]

useful info/settings:
samples = 256
I render using my CPU
Max light bounces = 12
Denoising on def settings

Thanks.

Comment: I edited your post to embed the image, but next time please use the "add image" tool in the post editor...

Comment: See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Answer (score 3):

I have had the same with the denoiser when an area has had a high frequency noise. The denoiser can't know what pixels are fireflies and what are correctly calculated pixels. It just looks at the pixels and see a lot of white dots and think it’s the real thing. Same thing happens here where you have a high frequency texture and the denoiser considers an area that is too large into account when denoising.

Try setting the radius to something low, like 4 and the strength down to .2. Another alternative would be to deactivate denoising for diffuse direct to see if that helps. But I have never tried that.